# MotionEvent and the touch detector?

Tags: java, android, object-detection, motionevent

I want to ask a question:

I used a MotionEvent code to drag a button for a question and answer game I'm working on it, the thing is that I can't click on the dragged button anymore after I start dragging it, it looks like it stays always in ACTION_DOWN, I tried the CANCEL and UP actions too, but still same thing!

Also how can I make the dragged button do something when it touch another button or item (like i want it to detect the touch of the other items) like when the dragged button [btn1] touches another button [btn2] it will change the color for example!!

3 problems:

- it wont get up
- you cant click on it anymore
- touch detect

any suggestion how to fix that plz! and ty in advance

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.text.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.animation.*;
import android.view.animation.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.view.View;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private Timer _timer = new Timer();

        private double res = 0;
        private double lvl = 0;
        private String message = "";

        private LinearLayout linear3;
        private TextView textview13;
        private LinearLayout linear11;
        private LinearLayout linear13;
        private LinearLayout linear12;
        private LinearLayout linear8;
        private Button button1;
        private TextView textview14;
        private Button button4;
        private Button button2;
        private Button button3;

        private TimerTask m;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            initialize();
            initializeLogic();
        }

        private void initialize() {

            linear3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear3);
            textview13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview13);
            linear11 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear11);
            linear13 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear13);
            linear12 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear12);
            linear8 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear8);
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            textview14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview14);
            button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                        PointF DownPT = new PointF();
                        PointF StartPT = new PointF();
                        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            int eid = event.getAction();
                            switch (eid) {
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                                button1.setX((int)(StartPT.x+mv.x));
                                button1.setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y));
                                StartPT = new PointF(button1.getX(), button1.getY());
                                break;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : DownPT.x = event.getX();
                                DownPT.y = event.getY();
                                StartPT = new PointF(button1.getX(), button1.getY());
                                break;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                                break;
                                default : break;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    textview13.setText(message);
                }
            });

            button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCFD8DC);
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void initializeLogic() {
        /**
android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable gd = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable(); 
gd.setCornerRadius(30);**/
         /* radius */
        /*gd.setStroke(4, Color.WHITE);*/
         /* stroke heigth and color */

        m = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        lvl = 1;
                        textview14.setText("من هو مستر صلصا ؟");
                        button2.setText("مدير قناة صلصا");
                        button3.setText("صاحب سلسلة \nألف ليلة و ليلة");
                        button4.setText("لا أعلم");
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        _timer.schedule(m, (int)(1000));
        m = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if ((((SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button1) + 75) > (SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button2) - 120)) && ((SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button1) - 125) < (SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button2) + 120))) && (((SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button1) + 130) > (SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button2) - 60)) && ((SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button1) - 70) < (SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button2) + 60)))) {
                            res = 1;
                            button2.setBackgroundColor(0xFF64DD17);
                        }
                        if ((((SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button1) + 75) > (SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button3) - 120)) && ((SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button1) - 125) < (SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button3) + 120))) && (((SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button1) + 130) > (SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button3) - 60)) && ((SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button1) - 70) < (SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button3) + 60)))) {
                            res = 2;
                            button3.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);
                        }
                        if ((((SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button1) + 75) > (SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button4) - 120)) && ((SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button1) - 125) < (SketchwareUtil.getLocationX(button4) + 120))) && (((SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button1) + 130) > (SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button4) - 60)) && ((SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button1) - 70) < (SketchwareUtil.getLocationY(button4) + 60)))) {
                            res = 3;
                            button4.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(m, (int)(1000), (int)(100));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int _requestCode, int _resultCode, Intent _data) {
        super.onActivityResult(_requestCode, _resultCode, _data);

        switch (_requestCode) {

            default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to paste an example of your code, and go into a little more detail in your question of what you have attempted.

Comment: ohh ok , i will put the code

Comment: Right. You also need to use proper capital letters and punctuation.  We are not lolcats.  i should be I, u should be you.  Also no spaces are required before commas or exclamation marks.

Comment: ok , sry im new here & and ty for ur advices

Comment: have you set an onClickListener for your button ?

Comment: yes , but u can clicked the button only once then , u will never be able to click it again

Comment: that code is putted inside OnClickListener

Comment: nope, the onClickListener will always listen for clicks . may I have a look at your whole code ?

Comment: ok give me few minutes

Comment: ok the code is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

woah ! i accidentally found the solution

of all the problems !

i just changed :

`return true;` to `return false;`

i was just trying it to see the diffirence !!

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                        PointF DownPT = new PointF();
                        PointF StartPT = new PointF();
                        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            int eid = event.getAction();
                            switch (eid) {
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                                button1.setX((int)(StartPT.x+mv.x));
                                button1.setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y));
                                StartPT = new PointF(button1.getX(), button1.getY());
                                break;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : DownPT.x = event.getX();
                                DownPT.y = event.getY();
                                StartPT = new PointF(button1.getX(), button1.getY());
                                break;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                                break;
                                default : break;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    textview13.setText(message);
                }
            });
```

to this

```
int lastAction;

    button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                            PointF DownPT = new PointF();
                            PointF StartPT = new PointF();
                            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                                int eid = event.getAction();
                                switch (eid) {
                                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                                    button1.setX((int)(StartPT.x+mv.x));
                                    button1.setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y));
                                    StartPT = new PointF(button1.getX(), button1.getY());
                                    lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                                    break;
                                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : DownPT.x = event.getX();
                                    DownPT.y = event.getY();
                                    StartPT = new PointF(button1.getX(), button1.getY());
                                    lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                                    break;
                                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                                    if(lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                                      textview13.setText(message);
                                     }
                                    lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
                                    break;
                                    default : break;
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
```

for the second part you need to have the cordinates of your other item and then check if your `event.getY()` or `event.getX()` is in the range of the other item cordinates.

Comment: i think nothing changed , the problems r the same

Comment: @amiine I have updated my answer, check the new code and see if it works fine. I have removed the onClickListener() .

Comment: lastAction=MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;

Comment: error ( cannot refer to the non-final local variable lastAction defined in an enclosing scope )

Comment: and same error for the IF and the  ACTION_DOWN/UP TOO

Comment: @amiine put this line `int lastAction;` befor onCreat()

Comment: before oncreat() , sry , but how ?

Comment: @amiine move this line `int lastAction;`  below this line of your code : `private Timer _timer = new Timer();`

Comment: sorry for the late ,i try it no errors but same problems

Comment: woah ! i accidentally found the solution

 of all the problems ! 

i just changed :

`return true;` to `return false;`

Comment: @fatemah go and add an answer change true to false i will vote u

Comment: thank you but there is no need to do that, you found it yourself mark your own answer as the correct answer.

Comment: ok , can i ask u another question or i have to make a forum question for it ?

Comment: I actually don't know the rules :D, but I would be glad to help you.

Comment: i have an other code that i need to figure out a solution for it , i think i will put another forum question , but i just afraid that they vote me down , cause this is my fourth account here lol